# Shrinkspace is failing in oracle with ora-30036

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table named OBFEED_STMT_DTL and it is having 14GB of data in it. Now I deleted around 50% of the data in that table using delete sql and hence I am expecting its size to become 7GB. Data got deleted as I expected but the size of the table is not changed. So I thought to run shrinkspace on thoese tables. I used below sqls to do that.

```
alter table OBFEED_STMT_DTL enable row movement;
alter table OBFEED_STMT_DTL shrink space;
alter table OBFEED_STMT_DTL disable row movement;
```

It took more than an hour and at the end I got the below error message:

```
alter table OBFEED_STMT_DTL shrink space
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'
```

Could you please help me how can I go ahead to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: Probably you need to increase the size of your undo tablespace or allow it to autoextend a little.

Answer (score -1):

If you get this error it could well be that:

(1) Your undo tablespace is set to autoextend

AND

(2) The file system it is on is full.

You can see what I mean here:

http://international-dba.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/ora-30036.html

**EDIT**:

The ways to "Reclaim space in oracle"

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:54178027703899

Comment: my undo table space is not autoextend. There is very less chance of getting my file system full. May I know if I have any alternate to do the same? and also may I know how much time I can expect to shrink 7GB space?